# How to display the variable in a seven segment LED?

Tags: arduino

My question is, how to display the variable in a seven segment LED? I want to refresh the display every two seconds, however if I execute like the code below, it does not display properly. Any solutions?

```cpp
#include "SevSeg.h"
int reading;
int tempPin = 0;
float tempC;
unsigned long StartTime = millis();
SevSeg sevseg; //Initiate a seven segment controller object

void setup() {
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    byte numDigits = 4;
    byte digitPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    byte segmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    sevseg.begin(COMMON_ANODE, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins);
    sevseg.setBrightness(90);
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long CurrentTime = millis();
    unsigned long ElapsedTime = CurrentTime - StartTime;
    if(ElapsedTime > 2000) {
        tempC = tempRequest();
        sevseg.setNumber(tempC, 2);
        sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly
        StartTime = CurrentTime;
    }
}

float tempRequest() {
    reading = analogRead(tempPin);
    tempC = reading / 9.31;
    return tempC;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment in your code already points out, you need to call `sevseg.refreshDisplay();` repeatedly and not every 2 sec.

Its's also mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg#displaying):

> **Displaying**
>
> ```
> sevseg.refreshDisplay();
> ```
>
> Your program must run the refreshDisplay() function repeatedly to display the number. Note that any delays introduced by other functions will produce undesirable effects on the display.

Which means you must run `sevseg.refreshDisplay();` on every `loop()` execution and not only when you change the number. And any use of `delay()` will make it not work.

```cpp
void loop() {

    unsigned long CurrentTime = millis();
    unsigned long ElapsedTime = CurrentTime - StartTime;


    if(ElapsedTime > 2000){
        tempC = tempRequest();
        
        sevseg.setNumber(tempC, 2);
        StartTime = CurrentTime;
    
    }
    sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly

}
```

Comment: thank you!  you are right, it only needs to change the number every two seconds not refresh every two seconds.